# sudo unable to write to /etc/profile

Tags: user-profiles, sudo, profile

I am following the instructions on [this site](http://beans.seartipy.com/category/grails/) for Grails installation, but am not able to write to /etc/profile like it instructs.

```
sudo echo ‘JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun’ >> /etc/profile
```

Instead, I get this error:

```
bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied
```

Why am I not able to write to the file even using sudo?