# output redirection with sudo

Tags: linux, shell, redirection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to append to a file as sudo?](https://superuser.com/questions/136646/how-to-append-to-a-file-as-sudo)
>   [sudo unable to write to /etc/profile](https://superuser.com/questions/54814/sudo-unable-to-write-to-etc-profile)

The following command does not work because the elevated privileges do not apply to the redirection.

```
sudo echo "myoutput" >> /etc/file_that_only_root_can_write
```

how can it be done?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/54814/sudo-unable-to-write-to-etc-profile/54867#54867

Comment: @akira you're probably right... I just started a new one because I didn't find those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
echo "myoutput" | sudo tee -a /etc/file_that_only_root_can_write
```