# How can I use sed in /etc/apache2/sites-available?

Tags: permissions, root, sudo, sed, file-permissions

I'm attempting to write a script that uses **sed** to copy the *default* file for apache and writes a new file, replacing `/var/www` (`$DOC_ROOT` below) with my own directory, `$NEW_SITES_DIR`. However, sed isn't operating correctly running under sudo: I get a **"permission denied"** error for the following:

```
sudo sed -ie 's:$DOC_ROOT:$NEW_SITES_DIR:g' < default > $NEW_SITE
```

I've tried to [spawn a sub-shell](https://superuser.com/questions/54814/sudo-unable-to-write-to-etc-profile)

```
sudo sh -c "sed -ie 's:$DOC_ROOT:$NEW_SITES_DIR:g' < default > $NEW_SITE"
```

and use [tee](http://embraceubuntu.com/2007/05/17/using-tee-to-write-to-files-and-the-terminal/here.)

```
sudo sed -ie 's:$DOC_ROOT:$NEW_SITES_DIR:g' < default | sudo tee $NEW_SITE
```

but I get a **"no input files"** error instead.

I'm sure the last two attempts I have written are a bit off. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

**ANSWERED**

Thank you to everyone for your help. Here is the exact command:

```
sudo sed -e "s:$DEF_SITES_DIR:$NEW_SITES_DIR:g" < $DEF_SITE | sudo tee $NEW_SITE
```

And here is a key phrase from [this reference](http://embraceubuntu.com/2007/05/17/using-tee-to-write-to-files-and-the-terminal/):

> Don’t lose sleep over this, but
>   someday it will come handy, and when
>   you can figure out why the “sudo” does
>   not apply after the “>” in your
>   command, remember tee and come back here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `-i`. That's telling `sed` to edit the file in place, but you're providing the file on stdin by redirecting it. Try dropping the `-i`.

There's really no need to redirect the input file since `sed` accepts a filename as an argument. If the read permissions on the file are restricted then `sudo sed` (and not using redirection) will take care of that. By not using `-i` the original file will be left intact.

The `sudo tee` should take care of the write permissions for output if that's necessary.

Comment: sudo tee was definitely the way to go. I've updated my question with the exact solution.