# ls with directory path shows files, but ls with file pattern does not?

Tags: linux

Why is this happening?

```
$ sudo ls /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/pg_log/
postgresql-2015-03-23_134626.log  postgresql-2015-03-25_000000.log  postgresql-2015-03-25_095920.log
postgresql-2015-03-24_000000.log  postgresql-2015-03-25_095626.log
$ sudo ls /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/pg_log/*
ls: cannot access /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/pg_log/*: No such file or directory
```

`ls /path/to/dir/` shows files, but `ls /path/to/dir/*` says no files found.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard is expanded by the shell **before** sudo is run. The current user can't access the files, so the string is passed literally to `sudo` and later `ls`. `ls` doesn't expand wildcards (it's the shell's duty), so it can't find the file named `*`.

Protect the wildcard by quoting and call a root shell to expand it:

```
sudo sh -c 'ls /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/pg_log/*'
```

Comment: Will enclosing the path with `*` in double quotes (`sudo ls "/path/to/dir/*"`) delay expansion to the appropriate time?

Comment: @Brian: No. You need to call a shell to do the path expansion.

Answer (score 3):

You’re experiencing an aspect of the problem discussed in
[`sudo` unable to write to `/etc/profile`](https://superuser.com/q/54814/150988)
and [How to append to a file as `sudo`?](https://superuser.com/q/136646/150988),
and the issue discussed in [Who deals with the `*` in `echo *`?](https://superuser.com/a/901189/150988) 
Your primary shell *interprets* each command you type,
including wildcards (also known as globs or filename patterns).  If you type

```
some_command *
```

the shell enumerates the files in the current directory
and passes them to the command; e.g.,

```
some_command black blue brown green orange red white yellow
```

Well, if *you* don’t have permission to read `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/pg_log`,
then your shell
doesn’t have permission to enumerate `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/pg_log/*`. 
The fact that, when the command *runs*, it runs as `root`, is too little,
too late — pathname expansion (i.e., wildcard interpretation) is done by then.

You can fix this with a trick discussed in the first two questions I referenced:

```
sudo sh -c "ls /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/pg_log/*"
```

This runs a privileged shell.  The privileged shell can then expand the `*`.